# responsive.css in the Wordpress should be prioritized

Tags: php, functions, css, wp-enqueue-style

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'style', THEMEROOT . '/css/style.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'responsive', THEMEROOT . '/css/responsive.css' );
```

I am using the above method to enqueue stylesheet, but what I want is not achieved.

Whatever I write in `responsive.css` should be prioritized(that means CSS written here should override everything else written in style.css.), but that is not happening. Is there a way to achieve it through something that WordPress provide?

## Update →

the whole idea is not to use `!important`, but still when the website is loaded in smaller screens than responsive.css should dominate or override style.css without using any `!important` tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to make sure the second stylesheet loads after the first, you can use the third argument of `wp_enqueue_style` to set a dependency, eg:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'styles', THEMEROOT . '/css/style.css', array() );
wp_enqueue_style( 'responsive', THEMEROOT . '/css/responsive.css', array('styles') );
```

As for having **all** the styles in *responsive.css* override *style.css*, that is going to entirely depend on the specificity of the targeting in each stylesheet, CSS being a Cascading Style Sheet, it would be worth researching exactly what that means if you aren't fully sure how it works.

Comment: what does this means → As for having all the styles in responsive.css override style.css, that is going to entirely depend on the specificity of the targeting in each stylesheet

Comment: @TheWPNovice What [janh2 wrote](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/283293/108180). In general, the more specific rule wil be applied, no matter which was first. `body > div > .child` will rather be applied than `.child`

Comment: after implementing this , array('style')  the responsive.css doesn't even load. !important is not a great practice.

Comment: that's very strange, this is common practice I have this working fine in many places... maybe try changing the `style` handle in both places for something else and add an empty dependency array to the first line (see edit.)

Comment: @TheWPNovice Yes `!important` is not a great practice, there's a lot more to CSS specificity than `!important`. The issue here is clearly just incorrect CSS. Please research [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Comment: I have updated my question a little bit.

Comment: also note rules wrapped in media queries should override existing rules of the same specificity. but it's unclear still whether you have the file loading fine now and not working or just not loading yet.

Comment: @majick Let me share something with you: [This is how I have enqueued styles](https://www.screencast.com/t/ex2JQAQX) and this is how the [stylesheets are behaving](https://www.screencast.com/t/m9dwAw6c). expected behavior was that this code from responsive.css should override the CSS coming from style.css → `    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;` but that is not happening now.

Comment: in short even after adding this → `, array('style')` responsive.css is not prioritizing.

Comment: @TheWPNovice I don't know if you still need help, but your problem is that the `style.css` is doing `.pwidget-one ul li a` while your `responsive.css` is only doing `pwidget-ext a`. They are not using the same selector. The style.css file is probably using a more specific one. You should copy the selector that the style.css file is using (i.e.  you should use `.pwidget-one ul li a` in your responsive.css to replace it.)

Answer (score 3):

Generally, what is loaded later will take prevalence if both are similar in their specificity, e.g. `body { background-color: white; } body { background-color: black; }` will lead to a black background-color, while `body.myclass { background-color: white; } body { background-color: black; }` will result in a white background if body has the class myclass.

You can use three ways: load the overriding styles later, make them more specific or add !important after the attributes that you want to override, e.g.

```
body {
    background-color: white !important;
}
body.myclass {
    background-color: black;
}
```

will get you a white background. You can easily find out which one is loaded first by looking at your document source. If that is in the right order (if it isn't, tell WP that your responsive.css requires the original css and WP will make sure it's in the right order), make sure that your overriding styles are at least as specific as your original styles. If that is the case as well, make sure that your original style doesn't use `!important` for the attributes you want to override.

Comment: !important is not a great practice.